# Facebook share throwing connection error when sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-opengraph

Every article on the following website fails when attempting to share the page via the share link in our social media widget.

for example:

the following page, http://news.gc.ca/web/article-en.do?mthd=index&crtr.page=1&nid=957389 when shared via the following link:

Returns an `Error: Connection error` in the share preview window. Response headers for this request are:

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 14:22:20 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-FB-Debug: iYvCJSRJJqVdVXyIubD1kVq6teZBILIBRrCACZW9hI/Ms+B2qsquq52KyU5820UTfLmuXTis3LbRoL2bMlCVBw==
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1

200 OK
```

running the above URL through the `OpenGraph` object debugger returns:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

and the scraper sees the following for the URL:

```
Document returned no data
```

We need to determine the cause of this since none of our content can be shared from our site at the moment.

Any ideas, tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check on your end (access log, error log) what happens when the FB scraper tool tries to request that URL.

Comment: did check access logs and am seeing hits from facebookexternalhit agent... - - [30/Mar/2015:19:26:43 -0300] "GET /web/article-en.do?nid=957009 HTTP/1.1" 200 23429 "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" Not the same article as in my test above, but all of them are failing at this point anyways. Havent seen anything yet in error logs relating to this...but will keep looking.

Comment: Check with facebookexternal agent and paste the logs. That might help debug this.